# Netbeans Platform: excluding locales from war file in maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

When i build Netbeans RCP application via Maven my build always includes all localization jars: Russian(ru), Chinese(zh_CN), Japanese(ja) and Brazilian Portuguese(pt_BR). I would like to exclude these files. It increases build time and distributable artifact size. Localization jars take about 500kB.

As i understood nbm-maven-plugin puts these files into build. They locates here:

```
application/target/kws/platform/lib/locale
application/target/webstart/kws/branding
application/target/webstart/kws/org-openide-modules
```

And looks like :

```
boot_ja.jar
org-openide-modules_ja.jar
org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar
org-openide-util_ja.jar
boot_pt_BR.jar
...
boot_zh_CN.jar
org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar
org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar
org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar
```

Is there a way to exclude these files?

**UPD**: I've found similar problems but for ant ([1](https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/netbeans-platform-excluding-locales-from-zip-and-installer-distribution/), [2](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219753)).

Comment: were are these files located? can you post your pom.xml file?

Comment: @Apostolos i've updated my question please have a look

Comment: have you seen this? https://github.com/bitstrings/nbm-maven it adds extra functionality for excluding/including locales.

Comment: @Apostolos Nope. I'll try to use it and give you a feedback, thanks!

Comment: if it works, please let me post it as an answer so as to accept it. regards

Comment: @Apostolos i've tried this plugin it seems you're right there is only one way to exclude these files - this plugin. please prepare an answer

Comment: glad it worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vladislav, please have a look at [this](http://github.com/bitstrings/nbm-maven) github project. It adds extra functionality for excluding/including locales.

**Note**: This plugin has some restrictions:

- JDK 7 or higher
- compatibility issues with Netbeans IDE.